# Socket Communication Server/Client

Tags: java, sockets

I'm sort of new to Sockets and I'm attempting to write a program where I can basically send some simple requests from Client program to Server program.  Right now I just want to have in Client like 1 or 2 options that user can choose from.  For example if user chooses "Option 1" in Client then Server sends back a message "You choose Option 1" and so on, but I can't figure out how to read inputs on Server that has been sent from Client.

Client Code:

```
Socket socket = null;

    try
    {
        System.out.println("Connecting to Server");

        socket = new Socket("192.168.0.104", 7003);
        socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
        System.out.println("Connected");

        InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(input);
        PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        String line = buffer.readLine();

        //Not Sure which buffer to user here            
        System.out.println("Option 1");
        System.out.println("Option 2");
        System.out.println("Option 3");
        }

        System.out.println("Closing Client Connection");
        buffer.close();
        input.close();
        print.close();
        socket.close();
        System.exit(0);
```

Server Code:

```
    ServerSocket serverSock = null;
    Socket standSock = null;

    try
    {
        serverSock = new ServerSocket(7003);
        standSock = serverSock.accept();

        InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(standSock.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(input);
        PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(standSock.getOutputStream(), true);

        String dateTime = (Calendar.getInstance()).getTime().toString();
        print.println("You're connected to the Server at: " + dateTime);
        print.println("Type Q to disconnect");

        String line = read.readLine();
        //Not sure what to do here
        System.out.println("Client: " + line);
        print.println("Server" + line);


        System.out.println("Closing Server Connection");
        read.close();
        input.close();
        print.close();
        standSock.close();
```

Do I need two different BufferedReaders in Clinet one for user input and one for socket?  Really confused about this part.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The client needs to read input from the user and send it to the server. The server need to read from the socket and respond back to the socket. The client has to read from the socket and give an appropriate message to the user.  The server doesn't read or write anything to the user directly, only via the client.

Comment: So in the Client I would need two Buffers one that reads input from user and one that reads input from Socket?

Comment: Correct. In the client you also need to be able to write to the socket and to the System.out.

Comment: You have one PrintStream to the socket and another which is `System.out` which is provided for you. No magic as such. Its just that the clients has two inputs and two outputs.

Comment: Do you know of any examples like this that I can look at?

Comment: Thousands of examples, but none I can think of which do exactly what you are trying to do. Googling `java socket code` gives 20 million results. You have to adapt existing example to match your requirements.

Comment: Yea I've looked at ton of examples but none that I can find that do what I'm trying to get done.

Comment: Is there anything I can clarify further?

Comment: What exactly is the function of PrintWriter, just used for output on Socket?

Comment: In your case, yes. It can be used to write text with line separators.